# How can there be no idle talk in heaven?

Tags: allah, jannah

Allah says in 56:25 -

> They will hear no idle or sinful talk there,

I'm trying to understand what idle talk really is because if Paradise is eternal, then isn't all talk technically idle?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Looking into the context, that verse is applying to the talk of this world and saying how in paradise, there won’t be anything like it there.

By definition, idly means no particular purpose, reason, or foundation.

So basically as in talking without caring as much as what you’re saying. There is no real value to the conversation, it’s useless, waste of time, distracts you from God, hardens your heart, makes worship feel like a burden, and often leads to sinful conversations.

> This is one of the major blessings of Paradise, which has been mentioned at several places in the Quran, viz. that in Paradise human ears will remain secure against idle and frivolous talk, lying, backbiting slander, invective, boasting and bragging, taunts and mockery, satire and sarcasm. It will not be a society of foul-mouthed, indecent people who will throw mud at each other, but a society of noble and civilized people free of such frivolities. A person who has been blessed with some decency of manner and sense by Allah can very well feel what an agony it is in worldly life, a hope of deliverance from which has been given to man in Paradise.

This verse does not imply we won’t talk in paradise, we just won’t have useless/haram conversations there.

Comment: i still don't understand. How can useless conversation exist in heaven? In this world, time can be wasted, because it is limited. But paradise will last forever, so time can't be wasted

Comment: @Bobby What this verse implies is fowl speak like the examples listed above.